# Any way to clear default shared preferences using Robotium?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, robotium

My app uses `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext())`

and then sets a couple of preference values. While running tests I want to clear these values and start off from a known state. Is there any way default shared preferences can be set up or initialized in the `setUp` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you need is as following:

```
Context context = instrumentation.getTargetContext();
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().clear().commit();
```

If your application uses any different shared preferences you may need to clear them too in the following way:

```
context.getSharedPreferences("XXX", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();
```

Comment: Testing this out. I did try this out before but not sure if it worked properly.

Comment: Ok. Clearing stuff works but not able to initialize a shared preference. Does preferences.edit().putString() work here?

Comment: You can do everything you can from your own application as they run in the same process (assuming you get the targets context and not your own.)

Comment: You may want to think about the initializing thing though. Is this so your application is in a certain state or because your application needs shared preferences you cleared?

Comment: Yep. I want to check both scenarios. In some cases the SharedPreference variables need to be set, in others they should be cleared. I tried putString() from the test class but preferences.getString() returns a null just after that.

Comment: Post the code you are using. You might even want to create a new question as it is slightly different than the one asked. But doesn't really matter.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. Marking your answer as correct. Will try out stuff in more detail first. If I am able to clear preferences I should be able to set them too. Thanks!

Comment: Got values initialized the same way I was clearing them. Not sure what the problem earlier was but I suspect that clearing and setting the same value did not work one after the other.